# How to use the mentioned font in Latex

Tags: xetex, pdftex

[image]

The screenshot is taken from the book Elementary Analysis : The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth A.Ross (1st Edition).

Can anybody guess the font here. I am guessing that the font used is `ITC Veljovic LT Book` but I am not sure. Secondly, how do we use this font in LaTex. Is it possible?

Adding another screenshot, to get a view of the font.

[image]

Comment: @DG' : There is a possibility of a reprint afterwards, which i dont know. But the font matches very much with ITC Veljovic.

Comment: Infact if you look at the italics then you will come to see the similarities.

Comment: This font is very similar to `heuristica`.

Comment: If it looks like  heuristica,  which looks like `Adobe Utopia`, you might take a look at `fourier`, or even `fourier-otf` if you want to use open-type fonts.

Answer (score 2):

As Урош and Bernard said in the comments, it's quite probable that the original was set in `Utopia` and that therefor you could use `fourier-otf` (which actually is `Erewhon`, which is based on `Heuristica` which in turn, is based on `Utopia`) with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example 1}\\
Let \((s_n)\) be the sequence defined by \(s_n = n^2(-1)^n\). The
positive terms of this sequence comprise a subsequence. In this case,
the sequence \((s_n)\) is

\[(-1, 4, -9, 16, -25, 36, -49, 64,...)\]

and the subsequence is

\[(4, 16, 36, 64, 100, 144,...).\]

More precisely, the subsequence is \((s_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\) where
\(n_k =2k\) so that \(s_{n_k} =(2k)^2 (-1)^{2k}=4k^2\). The selection
function \(\sigma\) is given by \(\sigma(k)=2k\).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use OpenType fonts, you can try this. There may be a better way to do this, but this forms the basis of the template I have been using for years. Just replace "Adobe Garamond Pro" with the name of your chosen typeface.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

% For setting the section heading fonts
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec} 

% For specifying environment fonts
\usepackage{fontspec} 

% Choose the main and mono fonts:
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

% Use ligatures via fontspec:
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Set the font for the math environment:
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=1]{Garamond-Math} % This loads Garamond-Math as the main math font...
\setmathfont[range = up/num,Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}%...and then everything except the numerals get switched for Adobe Garamond Pro (because Adobe Garamond Pro doesn't have math symbols)

\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\date{18 November 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section}
Hello world.
$n^2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think it's Adobe Garamond Pro.

Comment: No, it's certainly not. I'm not sure what it is from the scan, but the above example should allow you to use it in LaTeX when you find it.